# Como crear un listado de clases diferentes en JACKSON

Tags: java, json, spring, class, jackson

Se me ha presentado el siguiente inconveniente. Tengo una estructura json la cual proceso en java con Jackson.

```
{
  "conditions": [
    {
      "operator": "AND",
      "conditions": [
        {
          "operator": "IS_DESCENDANT",
          "value": "a"
        },
        {
          "operator": "AND",
          "conditions" [
            {}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Por un lado, tengo una clase conditions y por el otro una comparison. El problema se me presenta cuando en una lista quiero representar dos clases diferentes como es el siguiente caso:

```
"conditions": [
  {
    "operator": "IS_DESCENDANT",
    "value": "a"
  },
  {
    "operator": "AND",
    "conditions" [
      {}
    ]
  }
]
```

¿Como le indico a Jackson que arme un listado con las dos clases diferentes? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que hago es representarlos como objectos con esta pagina http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

si debe llamarse igual los creo en paquetes diferente

ejemplo:
co.com.startoverflow.request.conditions 
co.com.startoverflow.response.conditions